# npm t killed and git diff not working because of an added addon.node

Tags: node.js, git, neon-bindings

For the past couple of days I have been struggling with this issue. I have this addon.node that is built using neon-cli trough npm. once this file is introduced to the git environment `git diff` stops working and the npm test gets killed before running any test even the ones unrelated to the specified addon.node.
[image: screenshot shwing the killed npm test]

Comment: "Killed by signal 9" on Linux and some other Unix-like systems means your OS is running out of memory (RAM + possible swap space). This has nothing to do with Git; it means "buy more RAM" (and/or rework your code to use less memory).

Answer (score 0):

This was mainly due to macOS code signing cache. The M1 requires shared libraries to be signed. It caches those validation by file location.

One solution was to remove addon.node before building it again.
another when there is git involvoled sometimes just checking out the file would do the trick

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).